# R read_excel from online web page link produces an empty data frame

Tags: r, excel, read.table, read.csv

Hi this is my first time posting,
I am trying to obtain data from an online web page link excel sheet. However,it works for the other links on the page but not a specific one which returns a blank data frame.

```
library(readxl)

download.file("https://www.parismou.org/sites/default/files/2016-04-DetentionLists_0.XLS","test.xls",mode="wb")
tbls=read_excel("test.xls")
```

Downloading it as a .xls file works fine but reading it doesnt work.
I have also tried using:

```
tbls=read.table("https://www.parismou.org/sites/default/files/2016-04-DetentionLists_0.XLS", header=TRUE, skipNul= TRUE)
```

which returns:

```
Error in read.table("https://www.parismou.org/sites/default/files/2016-04-DetentionLists_0.XLS",  : 
  no lines available in input
```

I have also tried the XLConnect packages but those returned the following error:

```
require(XLConnect)
download.file("https://www.parismou.org/sites/default/files/2016-04-DetentionLists_0.XLS","test.xls",mode="wb")
tblspx=loadWorkbook("test.xls")

Error: OldExcelFormatException (Java): The supplied spreadsheet seems to be Excel 5.0/7.0 (BIFF5) format. POI only supports BIFF8 format (from Excel versions 97/2000/XP/2003)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also failed to read the sheet with the readxl package. But got all the data into R by copying it and pasting into another sheet in a new file and saved and specifying the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with a very old excel format. The `gdata` package can deal with that (see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724923/impossibility-of-loading-a-excel-5-0-7-0-biff5-format-file-in-r)):

```
install.packages("gdata")
require(readxl)

download.file("https://www.parismou.org/sites/default/files/2016-04-DetentionLists_0.XLS","test.xls",mode="wb")

tbls = gdata::read.xls("test.xls", fileEncoding="latin1")
```

Comment: Thanks very much, had to download Perl to make it work, but it runs perfectly now